# Extracting one set of values from an array

Tags: user-interface, swiftui, user-experience

Total n00b question. How do I extract and display just a single set of items from an array?

Here I declare the array. I use a form overlay to populate it.

```
struct visitItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let visitDate: Date
    let visitType: String
    let medCategory: String
}

class Visits: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Items") {
            if let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([visitItem].self, from: savedItems) {
                items = decodedItems
                return
            }
        }

        items = []
    }
    @Published var items = [visitItem]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(items) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Items")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here I want to display just a single set of a date and two strings. But am currently using a List just to get something to show up. The List, as expected, displays all dates and strings.

```
struct Home: View {
    @ObservedObject var visits = Visits()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
//                let firstDate = visits.items { $0.visitType }
                List(visits.items) { item in
                    let firstDate = item.visitDate
                    let firstType = item.visitType
                    let firstCategory = item.medCategory
                
//                    Text("test \(visits[0])")
                    
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("You have a \(firstType) appointment on \(firstDate, style: .date) for \(firstCategory).")
                            .font(.headline)
                        }
                    }
```

I want just a single line of text:

```
You have a [firstType] appointment on [firstDate] for [firstCategory].
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations with and without List and ForEach. Nothing besides the current will compile.

Comment: Please edit your question by pasting in your code as text. Do not include screen shots of code unless absolutely necessary (for example to show IDE overlays).

Comment: You seem to be confusing tuples and arrays. In Swift, tuples are specific types that hold compound values, while arrays are of course ordered collections of a particular type. I don't see any tuples in your code, and you seem to be asking about `items`, which is an array.

Comment: Thank you @Caleb. I've been confused about that for sure. Edited for correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of items. You need to consider several possibilities:

1. The array might be empty. What do you want to display in this case?
2. The array might contain a single item. Then you just want to display that item.
3. The array might contain more than one item. Which item do you want to display? The item at index 0? The item with the earliest `visitDate`? The item with the earliest `visitDate` that is later than right now?

Here is one way to answer address those possibilities:

```
struct NextVisitView: View {
    @ObservedObject var visits: Visits

    var body: some View {
        switch visits.items.count {
        case 0:
            Text("No visits scheduled.")

        case 1:
            view(for: visits.items[0])

        default:
            let item = visits.items.min(by: { $0.visitDate < $1.visitDate })!
            view(for: item)
        }
    }

    private func view(for item: VisitItem) -> some View {
        Text("You have a \(item.visitType) appointment on \(item.visitDate, style: .date) for \(item.medCategory).")
            .font(.headline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this Rob. It's exactly what I needed and I appreciate the advice for the three possibilities. Hadn't thought about that yet.